# How to find second and max date and compare these two

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I need to find the highest and second highest date from every SKU(number) and compare these 2 dates 
and see if there is a 3 months difference.

down below is my code I already found the second highest date but I can't seem to make it work with a highest date in combination anyone for the rescue ?

code :

```
WITH X0 AS (
   SELECT 
 od.odscheduleid
,lc.shortname as line
,ar.erpcode as SKU
,ar.shortname as Article
,od.[PlannedEndInflow] as PlannedEndInflow
,od.[PlannedStartInflow] as PlannedStartInflow
,st.shortname as 'status'
,od.[ShortName] as 'order'
,od.[ERPCode] as ERPCode
,od.[ASCode] as ASCode
,od.[PlannedQuantity] as PlannedQuantityPC
,cast(od.[PlannedQuantity]*ar.Volume/100 as decimal(12,2)) as PlannedQuantityHL
,od.[PlannedChangeoverTime] as PlannedChangeoverTime
,od.[PlannedSpeed] as PlannedSpeed
,od.[PlannedSpeedRatio] as PlannedSpeedRatio,
         ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ar.erpcode order by od.PlannedEndInflow desc) as rn 
     FROM (  

       [RM].[TblDatODSchedule] od

          inner join [EM].[TblLstLocation] lc on od.locationid=lc.locationid
          inner join [RM].[TblLstART] ar on od.artid=ar.artid
          inner join [EM].[TblLstStatus] st on od.statusid=st.statusid

           )
            where lc.ShortName = 'fil 3'--replaces lc.shortname in (@line)(reportserver)


), X1 AS (
     SELECT SKU,PlannedEndInflow, RN FROM X0 WHERE RN=2
), X2 AS (
     SELECT SKU, line ,Article, PlannedStartInflow,PlannedEndInflow,PlannedQuantityPC,PlannedQuantityHL,PlannedChangeoverTime,PlannedSpeed,PlannedSpeedRatio,ERPCode,ASCode, PlannedEndInflow as most_recent_date , RN FROM X0 WHERE RN=1
)

SELECT 
 case when DATEDIFF(day,X1.PlannedEndInflow,most_recent_date) >=91 then DATEDIFF(day,X1.PlannedEndInflow,most_recent_date)*0.0328549112  
     -- when  exists( select 1 from x1 where x1.sku = x2.SKU having count(sku) > 1) then 123
else null end as MONTHDIFF,
--SELECT DATEDIFF(day, X1.PlannedEndInflow,most_recent_date) AS MONTHDIFF,

        line,X1.SKU,article,PlannedStartInflow,x2.PlannedEndInflow,x1.PlannedEndInflow,PlannedChangeoverTime,PlannedSpeed,PlannedSpeedRatio,ERPCode,ASCode,PlannedQuantityPC,PlannedQuantityHL
FROM X1
   left JOIN X2 ON X1.SKU=X2.SKU

   where most_recent_date >='20200410' -- replaces most_recent_date > @starDate(reportserver)
   -- add exception where never used SKU's are also shown !
```

Comment: `WHERE RN = 1` will give you the max date. Therefore `RN IN (1,2)` will give you both.

Comment: this indeed gives the highest and second date but can I make a calculation  with these 2 dates to find the difference if written like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to sketch the answer I mean rather than try to make it perfect with your query. This uses three CTEs. X0 assigns the RN value. X1 picks out where RN=1 and X2 picks out where RN=2. Then you join X1 and X2, and do your calculation.

```
WITH X0 AS (
   SELECT somecolumns,
         ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ar.erpcode order by od.PlannedEndInflow desc) as rn 
     FROM ( table join table join table )
     WHERE conditions
), X1 AS (
     SELECT somecolumns, RN FROM X0 WHERE RN=1
), X2 AS (
     SELECT somecolumns, RN FROM X0 WHERE RN=2
)
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, X1.datefield, X2.datefield) AS MONTHDIFF,
       X1.othercols, X2.othercols
FROM X1
   INNER JOIN X2 ON X1.something=X2.something
```

Comment: hey ross is there a way to exclude nulls from the MONTHDIFF i have made a case when from it ? @ross presser

Comment: Add to the bottom: `WHERE X1.datefield IS NOT NULL AND X2.datefield IS NOT NULL`

Comment: hey Ross sorry for the questions. how do I add when an SKU has never been used before I also need to show those ? So for example SKU(12345) is added to the database but is the only record with that number Those i need to show too. any idea how i need to implement this. thanks in regards !

Comment: could you help me out with this one ? @Ross Presser

Comment: Try a LEFT JOIN in the last clause instead of INNER JOIN ?

Comment: hey ross sorry I updated my code above as you can see the codes works fine I only need to add that when an SKU has never been used before I also need to show those ? So for example SKU(12345) is added to the database but is the only record with that number Those i need to show too. what  i do now i show the ones that are older than 3 months in the alias column monthdiff  now i need to add the above explained feature too so my report shows older than 3 month skus and new skus thanks in regards ! @Ross Presser

Comment: I've given my best idea on how to add items that have only one occurrence. Without seeing your entire exact code, including all CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements, there is not enough information for me to give any more advice. This is way beyond the original SO question now and I'm not going to respond any more to you, here or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple bit of sql that will return the maximum date, and a different one that will return the second maximum date for a given SKU you can write a function for each one that takes the SKU as a parameter and returns a date.

These can then be used inline in any sql where you have access to the SKU.

It's well worth using functions for things like this as they can be used in any part of a sql statement.

This is an example function that we use in our company.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTopContactId]
    (@client int) 
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @result int
    SELECT TOP 1 @result = contact
                    FROM contact
                    WHERE contact.client = @client AND contact.active = 1
                    ORDER BY
                        contact.copycont DESC,
                        contact.primarycont DESC,
                        Name ASC
    return @result
END
```

Comment: I don't think this is a wise way to go. This function will not be parallelizable at all. You'd do better to use CTEs.

Comment: I've not come across the acronym CTE before, what does it stand for.  (always looking for better ways to do stuff)

Comment: [Common Table Expression](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cte/).  Very similar in effect to a subselect, except that 1) it's at the front of the total query rather than the middle, and 2) you can actually do recursion.